# How to return data to templates from custom validator in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-validation

When creating a **custom validator** in Angular we have to return a javascript object (with true value) when an error is found (at least this is what I read on official documentation).

```
validate(formControl: FormControl) {
   if(error){
      return {"errorCode" : true};
   }
   return null;
}
```

I'm wondering what is the correct way to **return data to the template**. Can I replace the boolean value (true) with another object containing the data I want to sent to templates?
The following code is correct?
I can't find an official "answer" on the official documentation

```
  validate(formControl: FormControl) {
       if(error){
          return {"errorCode" : {
                                 "data1" : "I'm the data"
                                }
                 };
       }
      return null;
    }

 <input type="text" #name="ngModel" >
 <div *ngIf="name.errors.errorCode">
     The data: {{name.errors.errorCode.data1}}
 </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Whatever you will return in validation it will be added in error object.

Comment: Yea according to documentation you can return whatever you want  `{[key: string]: any} | null`, **any** is mentioned. Have you tried your second validator?

Comment: @tufonas thank for your help. Yes, I alredy tried the second validator and it works, but besides the fact that it works I wanted to be sure it was the "right" solution.  Thank you again :)

Comment: @Devang Patel thank for the help. Now I get that I can return "any" data I want from the validator, I thought I could return  only a "true" value. My mystake :)